# FFMPEG gets in never ending condition while live streaming on YouTube

Tags: actionscript-3, ffmpeg, youtube, encode

I have been working in AS3 to stream 1080P video on YouTube and video gets start uploading and almost 4-5 minutes of the video has been uploaded successfully and afterwards YouTube shows that stream has been ended, but FFMPEG will never hits on "Exit" or any other method even after waiting for next 10 minutes.

Below is the method I am using.

```
public var _nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo;
public var _processArgs:Vector.<String>;
public var _process:NativeProcess;
protected function StartVideo_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("ffmpeg.exe Path");
    _processArgs.push('-re');
    _processArgs.push('-i');
    _processArgs.push(VideoPath);
    _processArgs.push('-vcodec');
    _processArgs.push('copy');
    _processArgs.push('-acodec');
    _processArgs.push('copy');
    _processArgs.push('-maxrate');
    _processArgs.push('4500k');
    _processArgs.push('-bufsize');
    _processArgs.push('9000k');
    _processArgs.push('-pix_fmt'); 
    _processArgs.push('yuv422p');
    _processArgs.push('-preset');
    _processArgs.push('fast');
    _processArgs.push('-ac'); 
    _processArgs.push('2');
    _processArgs.push('-r'); 
    _processArgs.push('30');                            
    _processArgs.push('-g');
    _processArgs.push('60');                            
    _processArgs.push('-ar');
    _processArgs.push('44100');
    _processArgs.push('-f');
    _processArgs.push('flv');                   
    _processArgs.push(streamurl+'/'+streamname);
    _nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = _processArgs;
    _process = new NativeProcess();
    _process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
    _process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, progress);
    _process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
    _process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOErrorNativeProcess);
    _process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOErrorNativeProcess);
    _process.start(_nativeProcessStartupInfo);
}
public function onIOErrorNativeProcess(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(event.toString());
}
public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("Got: ", _process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(_process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable)); 
}
public function progress(e:ProgressEvent):void 
{
    trace(e);
}
public function onExit(e:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
{
    trace(e);
}
```

I have tried with 720P video too by changing bit rate from 4500k to 2500k which is as per YouTube and it is working fine but with 1080P something not went as per expectation.

Here are the video details:
Resolution : 1920*1080
Data Rate : 3220kbps
FrameRate : 20
[image: Video Description]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` so everything from `-maxrate` to `-ar` is being ignored, but I don't know why it is not exiting. It could be an issue with ffmpeg or with your code or both. So you should run the same ffmpeg command manually, unscripted. Does it still never exit? Also, show the log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: @Nayan, Still no response about _" Does it still never exit"_ if you use command line window instead of AS3 to run FFmpeg? Or is the problem fixed now?

Comment: Sorry @llogan & @ VC. One for alte reply, but issue is not with the ffmpeg part it is happening due to "progress" function. I had rectified the issue last night only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two problem with the following code.

1. In the "progress" function I am not reading actual log of the FFMPEG, have to update progress event like below.

   ```
   public function progress(e:ProgressEvent):void 
   {
       trace("Progress: ", _process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(_process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
   }
   ```
2. For now I have just traced the log and code is working properly in Debug mode after creating build issue has been happening and after that I have logged all the data in file and then even after creating build everything is working fine.

I  don't know the exact reason behind it, but this solution help me for now.

Thanks